# Error when run the java applet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have did the following steps to create Creating Self-Signed Applets

Also, it gave me error when i run on the html page, I use both HTML 4.1 and HTML5

```
eytool -genkey -keystore mykeystore -alias myalias
Enter keystore password:  mypassword
What is your first and last name?
  [Unknown]:  
What is the name of your organizational unit?
  [Unknown]: 
What is the name of your organization?
  [Unknown]:  
What is the name of your City or Locality?
  [Unknown]: 
What is the name of your State or Province?
  [Unknown]:  
What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
  [Unknown]:  
  [no]:  yes
Enter key password for <myalias>
            (RETURN if same as keystore password):


and create mykeystore but i used jdk 1.7.0
after that i created the jar file by the following steps

C:\Users\Rahand\Desktop\draft>javac AudioRecording.java

C:\Users\Rahand\Desktop\draft>jar cvf AudioRecording.jar *.class
added manifest
adding: AudioRecording$1.class(in = 673) (out= 445)(deflated 33%)
adding: AudioRecording$2.class(in = 812) (out= 499)(deflated 38%)
adding: AudioRecording$CaptureThread.class(in = 1840) (out= 983)(deflated 46%)
adding: AudioRecording.class(in = 3227) (out= 1723)(deflated 46%)

C:\Users\Rahand\Desktop\draft>pack200 -r AudioRecording.jar


C:\Users\Rahand\Desktop\draft>jarsigner -keystore mykeystore -storepass (secretkye) -keypass (secretkye) AudioRecordin
g.jar myalias

Warning:
The signer certificate will expire within six months.
```

but when i run on the web the program has the following error

```
load: class JavaSound.class” />  <param name= not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: JavaSound.class” .>  <param name=
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: JavaSound.class” .>  <param name=
```

i am appreciated if help me to solve this problem...
Thanks

Comment: Is it working right when using AppletViewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your stacktrace :

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: JavaSound.class
```

Does `JavaSound.class`  really exists in your jar file?

because when I see the jar compile stacke it looks like :

```
adding: AudioRecording$1.class(in = 673) (out= 445)(deflated 33%)
adding: AudioRecording$2.class(in = 812) (out= 499)(deflated 38%)
adding: AudioRecording$CaptureThread.class(in = 1840) (out= 983)(deflated 46%)
adding: AudioRecording.class(in = 3227) (out= 1723)(deflated 46%)
```

There is no class as `JavaSound` int your compiled `jar` file.

you should use `AudioRecording.class` instead of `JavaSound.class` in your `param value`